# Responding to a recruiter email when you are interested but not ready "right now"

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, email, correspondence

I had an interview last year with one of the largest companies in my domain and which for many is a dream employer.

I did not pass it and now they have mailed me asking if I would be interested in applying again.

Now though I am interested, after going through the process last year, I feel I am not ready for an interview right now because I would need a good amount of preparation time.

What would be the best way to respond to them saying you are interested but not right now?

Edit: So I went ahead and said that though i am very much interested I may need time to prepare and they responded positively saying no need to rush :).

Comment: Do you have a firm idea of how much prep time you'll need?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, "I am interested but not right now" is considered as a no from the recruitment perspective, as they cannot possibly know *when* one will be "ready".

If you're up for it, go for it. Otherwise, wait till the next time they have an opening that suits your need. There's no middle way to keep the thread open/ hanging.

And while communicating, be straightforward about it (no confusion and no wastage of time/effort), however you don't need to provide them with any specific reason. Mention something like

> *"Thanks for reaching out, but at the moment I'm not in a position to make a career switch, however, I'll love to hear about future opportunities."*

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sourav's answer. I'd just add that if they are asking to apply again, it's likely that you were close the first time and if the meantime you learned something more, I guess that you are more ready than you might think. So my suggestion, given that this is your dream job, is to apply again, invest all the time you will have in preparing and hope for the best.

Good luck!